# Yii2 - Cell Edit

Tags: css, colors, yii2, cell

How to edit cell CSS (like background color) in gridview? 
Note that I only need to edit one cell not the whole column or row.
Specifically, there is a column in grid view that's labelled 'colors', I want every cell's background color to be the same as the color written there.

Comment: Explain Better what do you mean with 'edit one cell'.?  You want change the color of a cell using css. ?

Comment: I want to change the background colour of every cell in the color column by any means. I wrote CSS because think it's the only way to edit the background color. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gridView, in every column, you can set the `contentOptions`  and `value` paramter

this is a sample where:

for a first column  you assign the color for all cell of the column,

in the the second column you can assign the color for single cell based on a color value ( in this sample the color value is provided by model) evaluated inside the function. Then composing the proper html code and render in row format you set the color you desire

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            [
                'attribute' => 'your_attribute',
                'label' => 'your_labe',
                'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'background-color: #000000;'], 
            ],
            ....
            ....

            [
                'attribute' => 'your_attribute_cell',
                'label' => 'your_label_cell',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function ($model) { 
                    return  "<span style='background-color:" . $model->yourColor  "'  >"  . $model->your_attribute_cell. " </span>";
                },
                'contentOptions' => ['style' => ' text-align: center; width: 100px;'],
                'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align: center;'],
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: Well thanks a lot! That worked and answered half my question. I only need to make the color of each cell the same as the color written inside it.. Should I make a color table and give every color its code? @scaisEdge

Comment: Many thanks man :) I'll work on it now. But by saying that the color value is provided by a model you mean that i need to create a table for colors, right? @scaisEdge

Comment: is an indication, I do not know how you would like to change the colors to your cells. You can use a value that you assigned to the model or the dataProvider can be connected to the GridView or whatever value you get in the calculations function. If it suits you, you can use a table and put it in relation with the field or questioning inside the function. it's your choice of programming

Comment: :)
I've just finished it. To get the best result and have the colour fill the cell, it needed some work.